# strtok with reading lines from file in C

Tags: c, string, split, fgets, strtok

Reading cities and their coordinates from a file and calculating their distance to the point (lat1;lat2) I combined fgets with strtok like this:

```
const char sep[]=";";
char data[99];
char *token;
int a=0;
double x1,x2,y1,y2,xx,yy,d;

FILE * f=fopen("miasta.txt", "r");
while(fgets(data,sizeof(data),f))
{
    token=strtok(data,sep);
    while(token!=NULL)
    {
        switch (a) {
            case 0: printf(token); break;
            case 1: x1=atoi(token); break;
            case 2: x2=atoi(token); break;
            case 3: y1=atoi(token); break;
            case 4: y2=atoi(token); break;
            }

        if (a==4) {

            xx=x1+(x2/60);
            yy=y1+(y2/60);
            d=distance(lat1,lat2,xx,yy);

            printf(": %fkm\n",d);
            a=0;

        } else a++;

    token=strtok(NULL,sep);
    }

}
fclose(f);
```

I get output like this which only displays every fourth or fifth city correctly along with some random numbers probably from memory

```
Adamow(siedleckie): 309.497030km

: 4938.205291km
36: 3837.944678km
50: 5444.875905km
59: 5706.694715km
18: 2604.334104km
Aleksandrow Lodzki: 17.040912km

: 2966.025473km
04: 4119.540847km
51: 5465.558650km
20: 5658.932842km
22: 758.127409km
Annopol: 282.801168km

: 2260.260604km
51: 4206.333008km
52: 5364.594058km
26: 5665.585238km
15: 5109.704188km
Baborow: 238.291577km

: 4452.965697km
42: 3970.852437km
50: 5573.425585km
39: 5811.661294km
22: 3244.163706km
```

I really have no idea what's going on... Why does saved data get corrupted if it was stored in an independent variable? I saw the usage of strdup somewhere but I I couldn't implement it correctly I don't think I understand it.

Comment: Before  `while(token!=NULL)`, add `a=0;`

Comment: Posting some lines of data would help too.

Comment: `distance()` lacks declaration.

Comment: OMG Thank you adding `a=0;` worked! How does it fix it thought I'm even more confused, I already reset the a variable in the loop

Comment: I just didn't include the `distance()` function, cus it wasn't related to the problem

Comment: The reason for posting complete code is to eliminate candidate problems.  You might "know" something is not related, but it might be in unfamiliar ways.  IAC, I suspect data is not formatted as thought.  `a=0` as suggested copes with some ill formed data.  To get unconfused, post a [mcve]

Comment: OT: regarding: `FILE * f=fopen("miasta.txt", "r");`  Always check (!=NULL) the returned value to assure the operation was successful.  If not successful (==NULL) then call `perror( "fopen failed" );`  and exit the program via: `exit( EXIT_FAILURE );`

Comment: OT: regarding: `double x1,x2,y1,y2,xx,yy,d;`  those variable names are meaningless, even in the current context.  Please use meaningful variable names that indicate `content` or `usage` (or better, both)

Comment: OT:  Please follow the axiom:  *only one statement per line and (at most) one variable declaration per statement.*   The three statements:  `} else a++;` result in making the code much more difficult to read and understand.

Comment: OT: for ease of readability and understanding: Please consistently indent the code: Indent after every opening brace '{'.  Unindent before every closing brace '}'.  Suggest each indent level be 4 spaces.